# How to save Thai language in .txt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, text-files

I want get text as Thai characters in Edit Control to save in .txt file. The problem is that in the .txt file the Thai characters show up as `???` but English characters and numbers have no problem.

How can I do this?

```
char* getStringFromCString(CString& x) // code convert string
{
    char * temp = new char[(x.GetLength()) + 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < x.GetLength(); i++)
    {
        temp[i] = x[i];
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    return temp;
}

void CPictureDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSave() // Save.txt files
{
    CString ss[2];
    CITIZEN_ID.GetWindowTextW(ss[0]);
    Name_text.GetWindowTextW(ss[1]);
    char* citizen = getStringFromCString(ss[0]);
    char* name = getStringFromCString(ss[1]);
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    myfile << citizen << "\t" << name;
    myfile.close();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: How do you examine the `.txt` file? Do you know what encoding that tool uses? And what encoding is used in writing `Name_text`? And what is the type of `Name_Text`?

Comment: MBCS support in MFC is being deprecated. You should prepare your code to be future-proof by using Unicode instead. This isn't any news. The Windows NT line of products have been using Unicode internally for more than 20 years now (NT 3.1).

Answer (score 1):

- Problem

Firstly, you have to use Unicode. Please read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Secondly, Your `getStringFromCString()` have a problem which occurs memory leak.

- Method

Use Unicode, and `std:wofstream`, `std:locale` for Thai character set.

```
std::wofstream myfile;

//I just checked for Korean, you may need std::locale("thai").  
myfile.imbue(std::locale("kor"));

myfile.open("example.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
myfile << input.GetString();
myfile.close();
```

I hope this will help you a little. Happy new year~

Comment: Additional required reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)